# Running Multiple Jupyter Notebooks which use GPUs results in decreased performance

Tags: jupyter-notebook, gpu, conv-neural-network, nvidia

I'm using jupyter notebooks to train neural networks with GPUs.  Specifically I have 3 notebooks open and each is training a different neural network.

I'm experiencing a decrease in performance in the time to train each network.

When I run `nvidia-smi` I see the processes on each GPU and the associated GPU memory used.  The GPU memory used is not being maxed out on any 1 of the GPUs.

Is running multiple jupyter notebooks causing a problem?

If jupyter notebook causing the problem, what else could it be and how might I check?